# How to save or display a string of size having more than 65534 characters in a CLOB through Oracle forms 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

How to display or save a string having more than 65534 characters in a CLOB column **through a text field in Oracle forms 11g**?

If character size was less than or equal to 65534  characters then the below is possible, but I want to manipulate strings having characters larger than that:-

```
1. Create database data block
2. Set the type of CLOB item to LONG in form property palette
3. Set the size to 65534 characters
4. Set Item Type -> Text Item - Multi-line.
```

Additional Information about the software version that i am using:-

Forms [64 Bit] Version 11.1.2.2.0 (Production);
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production;
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a formsbean for this action instead of a normal field.
The following [link](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-12477145.html) contains the instructions and code to make such a formsbean. I used it before and it works very good.